# parallel animation in matlab

Tags: matlab, animation

I'm making a GUI with animation using Matlab and I have one question. I want animation was simultaneously on two plots, so I do:

```
for i = 1:numel(y)
    axes(handles.axes3)
    yspring = linspace(maxy + 1,y(i));
    xspring = ones(1,numel(yspring));
    set(spring, 'XData', xspring, 'YData', yspring);
    set(plummet,'XData', 1, 'YData', y(i));
    set(handles.edit8, 'String', num2str(T(i)));

    axes(handles.axes1)
    set(mark,'XData', T(i), 'YData', y(i));
    speedctrl = get(handles.slider1, 'Value')/10;
    pause(speedctrl)
end
```

But using axes(h) is slow and not recommended in loops (and it makes animation slower), so how should I rewrite this code to avoid the problem?
Thanks for advance.

Comment: I found solution, replaced axes(handles.axes1) with                 set(handles.figure1, 'CurrentAxes', handles.axes1)

Comment: You should post that as an answer, that makes your solution stand out better for random Googlers with the same problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, replaced axes(handles.axes1) with set(handles.figure1, 'CurrentAxes', handles.axes1)